# Does it matter what I name the ship?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

When unlocking the Kul Tiran allied race, Jaina asks you to name a ship, out of four options. The game tells you the choice is permanent, and it's what the ship is called from there on out. Other than being, well, the name of the ship that comes up every time you are on/near it, does this affect anything else? Does my name choice matter beyond a simple name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to be a purely cosmetic choice right now. It doesn't lock you out of any content or change any other content. At most it changes the response Anduin has when you turn in the quest.

Note that Blizzard up until this point has always been upfront about choices locking you out of rewards or gameplay, even if the choice can later be changed. even back in TBC, Khadgar warned players about the choice between Aldor and Scryers.